# Regarding ASN.1 Query

Tags: c

What is the scope of the ASN.1 currently in the market, also please give the some pdf or Doc, ebook free downloaded to create ASN.1 parser using C,C++ understandable and with more clear concepts

Answer (score 0):

Try a search engine with all these keywords.  ASN1 is widely used for efficient transmission and storage of complex information. Alas, due to obsessive use of bit packing, it is a very cumbersome standard to implement, I doubt you will find anything simple, clear and understandable.  xml and json are much more popular nowadays, with their own shortcomings.